# Windows ios sdk is less than mac ios sdk for xamarin

Tags: ios, windows, xamarin, mobile, sdk

So my mac has ios sdk 14.0 installed. When i pair the mac from visual studio it gives me the version mismatch error and wants me to downgrade the mac

[image]

Instead of downgrading i want to force windows to somehow be upgraded.

Comment: You need to update your xamarin in your windows machine, it was caused by xamarin version in windows is less than in your mac version

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had visual studio community preview installed. After installing regular visual studio community it had the v14.0 ios sdk